# Is there a speedier way to nest data by-group?

Tags: r, performance

I'm looking for a fast way to *summarize* a dataset:

- by-group
- collapsing rows by nesting values

For example, consider the `mpg` dataset from `ggplot2` package. Here we group by `manufacturer` and `year`, and nest `cty` values.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  summarise(nest_cty = list(cty))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'manufacturer'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#> # Groups:   manufacturer [15]
#>    manufacturer  year nest_cty  
#>    <chr>        <int> <list>    
#>  1 audi          1999 <int [9]> 
#>  2 audi          2008 <int [9]> 
#>  3 chevrolet     1999 <int [7]> 
#>  4 chevrolet     2008 <int [12]>
#>  5 dodge         1999 <int [16]>
#>  6 dodge         2008 <int [21]>
#>  7 ford          1999 <int [15]>
#>  8 ford          2008 <int [10]>
#>  9 honda         1999 <int [5]> 
#> 10 honda         2008 <int [4]> 
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

There are alternative packages that can give us some performance gain in speed:

- `data.table`

  ```r
  library(ggplot2)
  library(data.table)
  MPG <- data.table(mpg)
  MPG[, .(nest_cty = list(cty)), by = list(manufacturer, year)]
  ```
- `collapse`

  ```r
  library(ggplot2)
  library(collapse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  #> collapse 1.6.5, see ?`collapse-package` or ?`collapse-documentation`
  #> Note: stats::D  ->  D.expression, D.call, D.name
  library(magrittr)

  mpg %>%
    fgroup_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
    fsummarise(nest_cty = list(cty))
  ```

---

Evidently, `collapse` gives the speediest execution time:

```r
bench::mark(dplyr = mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, year) %>% summarise(nest_cty = list(cty)),
            data.table = {MPG <- data.table(mpg); MPG[, .(nest_cty = list(cty)), by = list(manufacturer, year)] },
            collapse = mpg %>% fgroup_by(manufacturer, year) %>% fsummarise(nest_cty = list(cty)),
            check = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 dplyr        4.69ms    5.5ms      184.    2.38MB     5.56
#> 2 data.table   2.37ms   2.51ms      391.    2.16MB     0   
#> 3 collapse     95.2us  101.8us     9560.  206.56KB     6.22
```

---

### The problem

**When we have very large data, even `collapse` is not as speedy as I wish**

Below I simulate some large data and show timings.


*code for data simulation function; no need to read*

```r
library(ids)
library(tidyr)

simulate_data <- function() {
  
  # util function
  generate_random_unique_ids <- function(n) {
    vec_ids <- ids::random_id(n = n, bytes = 4, use_openssl = FALSE)
    repeat {
      duplicates <- duplicated(vec_ids)
      if (!any(duplicates)) {
        break
      }
      vec_ids[duplicates] <- ids::random_id(n = sum(duplicates), bytes = 4, use_openssl = FALSE)
    }
    vec_ids
  }
  
  ids        <- generate_random_unique_ids(4e5)
  years      <- 1996:2022
  
  d         <- tidyr::expand_grid(ids, years)
  d$weights <- sample(5, nrow(d), replace = TRUE)
  d         <- tidyr::uncount(d, weights = weights) 
  d$vals    <- sample(letters, nrow(d), replace = TRUE)
  d         <- d[-sample(nrow(d), 0.5 * nrow(d), replace = TRUE), ]
  
  return(d)
}
```

*simulate the data*

```r
set.seed(2021)
my_df <- simulate_data()
my_df
#> # A tibble: 19,650,398 x 3
#>    ids      years vals 
#>    <chr>    <int> <chr>
#>  1 86a21d40  1996 c    
#>  2 86a21d40  1996 h    
#>  3 86a21d40  1996 v    
#>  4 86a21d40  1997 m    
#>  5 86a21d40  1997 f    
#>  6 86a21d40  1997 g    
#>  7 86a21d40  1997 b    
#>  8 86a21d40  1998 i    
#>  9 86a21d40  1998 d    
#> 10 86a21d40  1998 j    
#> # ... with 19,650,388 more rows
```

We can see that `my_df` contains 3 columns in long format.

---

**Bottom line:**

Even with `collapse`, grouping by `ids` and `years` then nesting `vals` is going to take quite some time.

```r
library(collapse)
library(tictoc)

tic()
output <-
  my_df %>%
  fgroup_by(ids, years) %>%
  fsummarise(nested_vals = list(vals))
toc()
#> 20.15 sec elapsed
output
#> # A tibble: 9,411,683 x 3
#>    ids      years nested_vals
#>    <chr>    <int> <list>     
#>  1 00000466  1996 <chr [3]>  
#>  2 00000466  1997 <chr [1]>  
#>  3 00000466  1998 <chr [1]>  
#>  4 00000466  1999 <chr [1]>  
#>  5 00000466  2001 <chr [1]>  
#>  6 00000466  2002 <chr [4]>  
#>  7 00000466  2003 <chr [1]>  
#>  8 00000466  2004 <chr [3]>  
#>  9 00000466  2005 <chr [4]>  
#> 10 00000466  2006 <chr [1]>  
#> # ... with 9,411,673 more rows
```

I tend to work with very large data, and processing times easily climb for such "nesting" procedure. Is there possibly a speedier method than the `collapse` example?

Comment: With `data.table` have you tried `setDTthreads(0L)` and then `setkey()`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur, I haven't. I'll look it up and try. Thanks.

Comment: In my system, `collap` gives slight performance improvement `output <- collap(my_df, ~ ids + years, custom = list(list = 3))`

Comment: Not sure if it gives a performance boost, but using summarize to nest columns by groups feels a bit odd. Why don‘t you go the direct way by using `nest(nested_values = cty)`?

Comment: @akrun, I now see the slight improvement of `collap()` over `fgroup_by() %>% fsummarise()`. Well, slight improvement is better than no improvement, so please consider posting your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Unless you believe there should be some other strategy out there to beat `collap()`...?

Comment: @Emman Thanks.  I haven't found any other option that beats the collap.  If I find one, will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `collap`

```
library(collapse)
output <- collap(my_df, ~ ids + years, custom = list(list = 3))
```

Comment: Interestingly, `collap()` has the `mc.cores` argument. Do you see any performance gain when using `mc.cores` > `2`? Because I've tried `mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()` but it was actually slightly *slower* than the default (which is `mc.cores = 2`).

Comment: @Emman I didn't change the cores.  Somecases, there is a performance decrease with that option